# React Native - Jest: Broken since update to 0.56. How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

Ever since upgrading to the new React Native version my tests are broken.

### Environment

Here is my environment:

```
React Native Environment Info:
System:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
  CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7920HQ CPU @ 3.10GHz
  Memory: 486.81 MB / 16.00 GB

  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 9.4.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  npm: 6.1.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 11.4, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11.4, watchOS 4.3
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4697961
  Xcode: 9.4.1/9F2000 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1
  react-native: 0.56.0 => 0.56.0
npmGlobalPackages:
  create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

### Description

While trying to test my newly created action creators,`npm test` throws the following error:

```
jest

 FAIL  app/actions/logout/logout.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run


    Plugin 0 specified in "/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js" provided an invalid
property of "default" (While processing preset: "/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js
")

      at Plugin.init (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/plugin.js:131:13)
      at Function.normalisePlugin (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:152:12)
      at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:184:30
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Function.normalisePlugins (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
      at OptionManager.mergeOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
      at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:265:14
      at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:323:22
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at OptionManager.resolvePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
```

I have googled heavily and can't find a fix. It seems like it has something to do with babel.

### Reproducible Demo

It's easy to reproduce (currently). I tried an started a new project using `react-native init`. Then I just created a random `.test.js` file and wrote the getting started test of the documentation in it:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

test("adds 1 + 2 to equal 3", () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Next I run 'npm test' and it gives the error above.

Comment: Maybe you are missing some babel plugins `"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"`

Comment: Why would react native out of the box miss plugins?

Comment: It's because I think that the latest version of `Jest` uses another version of `babel` that breaks the application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it.

Add

```
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
```

to your `package.json` and run `npm install`. This fixed it for me.

Furthermore for Enzyme you will have to add

```
   "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    }
```

to you jest config in your `package.json`.

If you want to see a more thorough fix, check out [this github issue.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19859)

Answer (score 9):

@J. Hesters solution is almost correct. But is not necesary to install babel, just adding the transform solves the issue.

```js
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

My previous response has some side effects that i did not see until after trying to rebuild the entire react-native application. So please dont use it.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

is actually nothing to do with react-native 0.56. is caused by the babel presets 5, just revert this package will do the trick.

`yarn add babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0`

Comment: Anybody else stuck in an update loop with Jest tests? I downgrade to 4.0 and break RN. Look up that error it says to upgrade to 5.0 so I do that and break Jest. Look that error and downgrade to 4.0 and break RN.. etc.. etc..

Comment: Where is is this code supposed to do? What file? package.json or .babelrc ? or something?!

Comment: where you have your jest configuration. in my case is package.json. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: with that link, you can also understand better what transform does.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same mistake, and also I added:

```
"transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    }
```

But then I got another mistake in another module, and to ignore it you need to add this code to your setup.jest.js file:

```
jest.mock('react-native-router-flux', () => {
    return {
        Crashlytics: {
            crash: () => {},
        },
        Answers: {
            logCustom: () => {},
            logContentView: () => {},
        },
    }
```

So after this code jest will ignore error in "react-native-router-flux" module in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with 0.56.0.

> The only solution is running it with v0.55.4

either install the v0.55.4 by:  `npm i --save react-native@0.55.4`

or when running the app run by: `react-native run-android --version 0.55.4`

This helped me, hope it helps

Comment: I think you meant `react-native init appname --version 0.55.4` not `run-android`.  That init command worked for me.

Comment: init appname thing is when you want to create the app in that version...
But if the app already has specified version then running in a Specific version can be done by that, I just gave to ways to go about it

Comment: Downgrade React Native yes that's definitely not the solution and the rest of this answer is unrelated.